# Install Dingo in Laravel 5.2 and get error when call the api

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I have install the Dingo with composer, and change the app.php file. After configure the app.php file, then i have publish vendor that, and get the api.php file.

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
    $api->get('users', 'EventsController@index');
});
```

Then i try `php artisan api:routes`

This is my result:

```
+----------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+----------+
| Host           | URI            | Name | Action  | Protected | Version(s) | Scope(s) |
+----------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+----------+
| api.kayice.com | GET|HEAD users |      | Closure | No        | v1         |          |
+----------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Then i `php artisan serve` go to localhost:8000/user 

It just show me this **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**
Could that anything is might miss for that?

---

**Edited**
I have added the provider in the app.php, i think after the vendor publish, the api working, then everythings should working. Or else is the laravel 5.2 problem?

Answer (score -1):

I figure out what is the problem now, i didnt add the prefix in the api.php. Therefore it didnt return me the value. 
**Edited**

But it still does not, most probably the system still no yet support well