# Dingo in Laravel 5.2 doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, dingo-api

I have similar issue with this one: [Install Dingo in Laravel 5.2 and get error when call the api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087510/install-dingo-in-laravel-5-2-and-get-error-when-call-the-api)

And I still don't know the answer.
I have tried this: https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Configuration to setup my Dingo. When I try to access the API, it returns nothing. 
Is there any solution?

Or Dingo simply just not compatible with Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Please flesh out your question a bit more

Answer (score 1):

add service provider in **config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
       Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
],
```

and make sure you have fill (not null) and add these at **.env** file

```
API_PREFIX=null
API_DOMAIN=null
```

then follow another steps in  https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause.
Turns out it's my server problem when I try to install nginx.

Now that I uninstall the nginx from my server, Dingo api is working again.